# How to check iphone model using swift

Tags: ios, swift

How we can check model of iPhone (e.g iPhone 4/ iPhone5) in Swift. Using following code I can check whether it is iPhone of iPod.

```
let iphoneModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
if (iphoneModel == "iPhone"){
        println("Iphone 4")
    }
```

I need to know specifically which iPhone model it is.

Comment: Kindly check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Comment: Give a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the following code. ([Reference from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift))

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
    case Unspecified
    case Phone
    case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}
```

and use it as:

```
if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
            println("IS_IPHONE_6P")
}
```

Comment: I created a Swift Class just for this purpose: 

https://github.com/mikeKane/findThatModel

Answer (score 5):

SWIFT 3

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
    case Unspecified
    case Phone
    case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}
```

and for the use

```
if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P{
    print("IS_IPHONE_6P")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4 + iPhone Xr, Xs, Xs Max support

```
import UIKit

enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int {
    case Unspecified
    case phone
    case pad
}

struct ScreenSize {
    static let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let screenMaxLength = max(ScreenSize.screenWidth, ScreenSize.screenHeight)
    static let screenMinLength = min(ScreenSize.screenWidth, ScreenSize.screenHeight)
}

struct DeviceType {
    static let iPhone4OrLess  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength < 568.0
    static let iPhoneSE = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 568.0
    static let iPhone8 = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 667.0
    static let iPhone8Plus = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 736.0
    static let iPhoneXr = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 896.0
    static let iPhoneXs = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 812.0
    static let iPhoneXsMax = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 896.0
    static let iPad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.screenMaxLength == 1024.0
}
```

And use :

```
 if DeviceType.iPhoneXsMax {
      print("is Max here")
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4:**

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
{
  case Unspecified
  case Phone
  case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize
{
  static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
  static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
  static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
  static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
  static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
  static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
  static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
  static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
  static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}
```

**Example case:**

```
 if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
      //TODO:
 }
```