# iOS app crashes for ad hoc installation

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ad-hoc-distribution

It works fine when I install through xcode, but when I export .ipa (Ad hoc) and install it on my iphone through iTunes it crashes. Below is the log file. Please, please please help if someone faced the similar issue.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1828f82d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19411c0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1828ff290 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 220
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1828fc154 ___forwarding___ + 928
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1827feccc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   ctapp                       0x1001bd84c function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of ctapp.ClassListVC.viewDidLoad (ctapp.ClassListVC)() -> () (ClassListVC.swift:49)
6   ctapp                       0x1001b9f28 @objc ctapp.ClassListVC.viewDidLoad (ctapp.ClassListVC)() -> () (ClassListVC.swift:0)
7   UIKit                           0x187338c84 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 692
8   UIKit                           0x187338994 -[UIViewController view] + 32
9   UIKit                           0x18746ee68 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 452
10  UIKit                           0x18746eb58 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 360
11  UIKit                           0x187346b6c +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 88
12  UIKit                           0x187472d90 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 236
13  UIKit                           0x187471c98 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 160
14  UIKit                           0x18734ff74 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 516
15  UIKit                           0x1874db328 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 916
16  UIKit                           0x1873edef0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 468
17  UIKit                           0x1873edcbc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
18  UIKit                           0x1873edc3c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
19  UIKit                           0x187335760 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 580
20  QuartzCore                      0x186c7de1c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
21  QuartzCore                      0x186c78884 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 320
22  QuartzCore                      0x186c78728 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
23  QuartzCore                      0x186c77ebc CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
24  QuartzCore                      0x186c77c3c CA::Transaction::commit() + 528
25  QuartzCore                      0x186c71364 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1828b02a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1828ad230 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1828ad610 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
29  CoreFoundation                  0x1827d92d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
30  GraphicsServices                0x18bfef6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
31  UIKit                           0x18739efac UIApplicationMain + 1488
32  ctapp                       0x100232c28 main (AppDelegate.swift:25)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x19479aa08 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001948b3270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019495116c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019482ab14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001938e9414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193908b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019411c3bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193905bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193905474 __cxa_throw + 132
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019411c200 objc_exception_throw + 344
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828ff28c +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 216
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828fc150 ___forwarding___ + 924
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001827fecc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
12  ctapp                       0x00000001001bd848 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of ctapp.ClassListVC.viewDidLoad (ctapp.ClassListVC)() -> () (ClassListVC.swift:49)
13  ctapp                       0x00000001001b9f24 @objc ctapp.ClassListVC.viewDidLoad (ctapp.ClassListVC)() -> () (ClassListVC.swift:0)
14  UIKit                           0x0000000187338c80 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 688
15  UIKit                           0x0000000187338990 -[UIViewController view] + 28
16  UIKit                           0x000000018746ee64 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 448
17  UIKit                           0x000000018746eb54 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 356
18  UIKit                           0x0000000187346b68 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 84
19  UIKit                           0x0000000187472d8c -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 232
20  UIKit                           0x0000000187471c94 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 156
21  UIKit                           0x000000018734ff70 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 512
22  UIKit                           0x00000001874db324 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 912
23  UIKit                           0x00000001873edeec -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 464
24  UIKit                           0x00000001873edcb8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
25  UIKit                           0x00000001873edc38 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 196
26  UIKit                           0x000000018733575c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 576
27  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c7de18 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
28  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c78880 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 316
29  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c78724 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
30  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c77eb8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 272
31  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c77c38 CA::Transaction::commit() + 524
32  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186c71360 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828b02a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828ad22c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828ad60c __CFRunLoopRun + 832
36  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001827d92d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
37  GraphicsServices                0x000000018bfef6f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
38  UIKit                           0x000000018739efa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
39  ctapp                       0x0000000100232c24 main (AppDelegate.swift:25)
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019479aa04 start + 0
```

Comment: Does your app takes a long time to start up?

Comment: Finally! found the issue. it was because I used UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() which only crashes in the distribution build! No idea why

Answer (score 0):

> If it can help someone. App crashes when I use
>   UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in swift.

Haven't you just answered your own question...?

Other people have reported the same issue..

[Detect current device with UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift)

..and suggested you can get around it using this...

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom
```

Comment: Did this Answer help you ?  Please click on the Up-Arrow if it did, and mark this as the answer.