# Set Constant for all Devices

Tags: ios, swift, size-classes

I'm trying to set a constant between iPhone (4,5,6...) and iPad, but I can't do a difference between iPhone 4 and iPhone 6 for example, so how to do ?

[image]

Comment: make an iboutlet of the constraint into the code, and change the constraint constant according to the current device, there are plenty of ways to check for device type using code.

Comment: First, its constraint. Second, if Size Classes is enable, please choose the `wAny hAny` below and change it according to the device type you want to config constraint to, then they will get the constraint that specify made for them

Comment: First all to run application also in ipad you need to set story board as UNIVERSAL application in places of using sizeclasses for iphone. To better understand regarding autkayout check https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: @Zazu Im looking to a code but I only find about Pad and Phone

Comment: @Tj3n But it don't do for each iPhones sizes

Comment: @Ben then its no other way than u have to create IBOutlet for each constraint then use code to detect the iphone...

Answer (score 1):

this question has a script that i use for this purpose

[Detect current device with UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift)

use it, and define constraints constant according to the device, and that's it. :)

Comment: Oh okay I see the second answer for each devices, I'm gonna try it