# How to set line width for different devices

Tags: ios, swift

I am drawing graphs for an app which is for iPad and iPhone.
I have managed to scale all the dimensions so that the graphs, axes, etc. scale correctly for different devices.
But I am unsure how to scale line widths.
So if I write:

```
context?.setLineWidth(4.0)
```

the line will appear quite thick on an iPhone 5 but thinner on an iPad. I would like to make it look thinner on the smaller devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift ?

Comment: Try take into account the scale of the device. ie. `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`. Returns 1.0 for non-retina devices like the iPad 2, 2.0 for retina devices like the iPhone 5, 3.0 for the 6 plus and 7 plus, etc.

Comment: If I want one pixel lines, I use `1 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`. I have actually a subclass of `NSLayoutConstraint` that converts its `constant` this way, therefore I can just set the correct values _in pixels_ in storyboard.

Comment: Here's a nice extension using UIDevice for device detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-iphone-model-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **LineWidth** as dynamic value based on the Graph or Screen Width, try like this

**iPhone 5**

```
let graphWidth = 320.0 //set screenWidth
var lineWidth = (graphWidth*(1.5/100)) // here you can change the percentage value
print("Line Width == > \(Int(lineWidth))") //Line Width == > 4
```

**iPhone 6**

```
let graphWidth = 375.0 // be dynamic graphWidth = graph width
var lineWidth = (graphWidth*(1.5/100))
print("Line Width == > \(Int(lineWidth))") //Line Width == > 5
```