# How to change navigation item font size for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to change title font of Navigation Item in the storyboard but I did not see any option to change title font of navigation item for different widths so I did this in my `viewDidLoad()` to change the size of font

```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad)
        {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 54)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]

}
```

What am I missing as I am not able to change font for regular width devices?

Comment: Why are you checking the interface idiom? Things should be done based on size, not a specific device.

Comment: And please explain your issue. You haven't stated what the problem is. Is the `if` statement true? Are you sure that `self.navigationController` isn't `nil`?

Comment: I did that because, I did not find Title Font for regular width size in storyboard interface.

Comment: Create a UILabel object.  Set an attributed string to that UILabel object.  Then add the label object to the navigation controller.  There might be an easier approach, but it at least works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that : [Device.swift](https://github.com/schickling/Device.swift)

Use `contains()` to check that your device type name include "iPad". So, it will do for all iPad Devices

**1. Drag UINavigationItem and put at your view controller navigation bar at storyboard.**

**2. Connect that UINavigationItem with the Outlet that is your code.**

```
@IBOutlet weak var rightNavItem : UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let navController = self.navigationController else{
        print("Navigation Controller is nil")
        return
    }

    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 25)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]

    //This code is for rightbarbutton

    rightNavItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 10)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], for:.normal)

    //.selected or .normal or .disable
}
```

That's all I got for now. Other feedbacks are also welcome on customizing UINavigationItem. If I can find new one which is better than this, I will update here. Good Luck.

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Actually it is working for navigation bar but I was looking for navigation item. I just edited my question.

Comment: Ok,let me take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad){
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24);
        titleLabel.text = "Check my size"
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: @Coder221, I have tested this in a brand new project, a UIViewController with UINavigationController, it works.  Did you test it in iPhone? If yes, you need to remove "UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad". If your  viewController doesn't belong to a NavigationController, it will fail also.

Comment: @Coder221, another solution if you are using Storyboard: Just drag a UIView into navigation bar title area. And then, drag a label into that UIView, you will be able to set the font of the label. Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't work in iPhone as well. My NavigaitonController is in ViewController.

Comment: in iPhone, you need to remove "if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad){".

Comment: yes I did remove it. Still doesn't work. But I have no problem with phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130989/discussion-between-yun-chen-and-coder221).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131003/discussion-between-yun-chen-and-coder221).

Answer (score 0):

First are you sure your device check is working?

I think UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() is Objective C. You should be using  something like this to check the device idiom in swift

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .unspecified
```

Then modify the title font size like this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 5.0)]
```

This should be enough to change the size of the nav bar title font size

Comment: Yes my check is working but the code you provided is not, also the code you provided is same as I used.

Comment: swift 3.0?... Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift

Comment: I don't have a problem with checking what device it is.

Comment: This is the funny thing... the code you provided it is actually working for me.  Could you share the class itself where this code lives?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130993/discussion-between-coder221-and-pato-salazar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131002/discussion-between-coder221-and-pato-salazar).