# Auto rotate portrait upside down to portrait for iphone X?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, iphone-x

As the *iPhone X* does not support orientation of `portrait upside down`. Is there a way to automatically rotate the orientation to `portrait` when user changes the orientation of phone to `portrait upside down` for *iPhone X* ONLY?

I am using this extension to support `all` orientations but I have researched a lot and have no idea how to achieve the above scenario

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask     {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you check this answer out. This has something about using the GBDeviceInfo framework to get the phone details probably the framework might have been updated for the IPhone X                                                         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Just replicating @BeslanTularov's answer for you here.

You should use this [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo) framework or ...

Apple defines this:

```
public enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int {

    case unspecified

    case phone // iPhone and iPod touch style UI

    case pad // iPad style UI

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case tv // Apple TV style UI

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case carPlay // CarPlay style UI
}
```

**so for the strict definition of the device can be used this code**

```
struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6_7          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P_7P         = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    static let IS_IPAD_PRO          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366.0
}
```

**how to use**

```
if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P_7P {
    print("IS_IPHONE_6P_7P")
}
```

**to detect iOS version**

```
struct Version{
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS7 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 8.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 7.0)
    static let iOS8 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 8.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 9.0)
    static let iOS9 = (Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0 && Version.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
}
```

**how to use**

```
if Version.iOS8 {
    print("iOS8")
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try placing your code specific to portrait upside down within this code

Comment: have you tried using screen height as an option. Considering each phone has a specific screen height you can maybe try approaching this problem using this way. this link has some info regarding that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x