# Snapkit lessThanOrEqualTo defaulting to preset

Tags: snapkit

I would like to set a buttons size to superview borders on smaller devices like the iPhone, but never let it get larger than 200 on devices like the iPad (my superview is a view that's part of a horizontal stack view with two views).

```
buttonControl.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(box).priority(.low)
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(200).priority(.high)
            make.height.equalTo(buttonControl.snp.width)
            make.center.equalTo(box).priority(.high)
        }
```

I would've expected the button to increase in size up to 200.

Instead, its maximum size is 64, the Snapkit preset. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing for a slider I was making. This worked for me:

```
    slider.snp.makeConstraints {(make) in
        make.right.equalTo(box).offset(-10).priority(.low)
        make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(350).priority(.high)
        make.top.equalTo(box).offset(10)
        make.left.equalTo(box).offset(10)
    }
```

I think you need to first set the "right" as a low priority, then apply the lessThanOrEqualTo as the high priority.

Answer (score -2):

The first part related to the device recognition: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift)

The second, is checking it type inside the `makeConstraints` method. 
If device is iPad, setup it like this: `make.width.equalTo(200)` in the other case change it to whatever.