# Image assets how to specify different images for portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, uiimageasset

xcode project has image assets we can specify image for both iPhone and ipad for a single image name

Is it possible I can specify image for portrait and landscape for iPhone and iPad separately

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate asset for iPad and check to see if it is an iPad before selecting the asset.  `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom`

See here for more discussion. [Detect current device with UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift)

Comment: I am confused. How can I have an image for ipad portrait and landscape