# SwiftUI: multi platform app check for iPhone vs Mac

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing a multi platform app that supports: iPhone (portrait), iPad (portrait and landscape) and Mac, in the main `ContentView` I want to display a `TabView` for iPhones, and a `NavigationSplitView` for other platforms (iPad and Mac), is the following check correct to do that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var hSizeClass
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var vSizeClass
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var selection: Panel? = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if hSizeClass == .compact && vSizeClass == .regular {
                
                TabView {
                    
                    
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                        HomeView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Home", systemImage: "home")
                            }
                    }
                    
                    
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                        SettingsView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            else {
               
                NavigationSplitView {
                    Sidebar(selection: $selection)
                } detail: {
                    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                        // shows view depending on selection
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What OS versions are you targeting? If iOS 16+ and macOS 13+, then [ViewThatFits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits) might be  a better solution than the manual checks.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 16.4+ and macOS 13.5+, I've tried `ViewThatFits(.horizontal) {  TabView{...}  NavigationSplitView{...} }` but it didn't work well on iPad, it keeps displaying the `TabView` instead of the split view

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can work but will not specifically check for the platform that you are on. To check the difference between iPhone or iPad you can use `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom`.

```
UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad // True for ipads
UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone // True for iphones
```

This is explained in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24059373/19115398

To detect macOS you can use `#available`

```
if #available(macOS 12.0, *) { ... } // Enters the if statement if system is on macos (in this case only macos 12 or higher but if you edit this to your minimum version it will always be true)
```

If you combine this you can check for all platforms and add the behaviour you need for it.